# svn: OPTIONS of 'https://...': could not connect to server

Tags: ubuntu, svn, https, proxy, svn-checkout

At work, I am trying to do a `svn checkout https://...` in a terminal, and I got the error: `svn: OPTIONS of 'https://...': could not connect to server (https://...)`

I can open the address `https://...` in my internet explorer, after entering the login and password, I can see the files in it.

Always in my internet explorer, my current setting of proxy is `None`.

Previously, to make svn works at home, people have inserted the following lines to my file `/etc/subversion/servers:`

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = kuzh.xxx.fr
http-proxy-port = 8080
```

Under this context, does anyone know how to solve this `... could not connect to server ...` error?

**Edit1** At the moment I am trying the same command at home, and it works. So I think @J.N. is right... I should make the `http-proxy-host` and `http-proxy-port` under a `[group]` so that it is taken into account only when I am at home, and not considered when I am elsewhere...

Now, the question is how to specify the `[group]` in `/etc/subversion/servers` so that it knows that I am at home or not...

Comment: Are you using the same computer at home and at work ? Have you tried commenting out your current proxy at work (if that doesn't work then you're probably stuck).

Comment: I use always the same computer... I havn't tried that, but I think that will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to comment the said lines to avoid using a proxy server and test if it works (that is add a `#` at the beginning of each line.

If it doesn't, then you're stuck. There is probably a proxy between you and the SVN server that prevents from using Subversion feautures (Note: some proxies are transparent, and need not be configured, they "catch" your requests automatically).

If it does otherwise, you can create a `[group]` section in the configuration to only use a proxy for some servers instead of a `global` configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, i use a proxy in my college, and no proxy at home.

It kept giving me the "could not connect to server" error.

All i had to do was comment the lines under the [global] section:

```
[global]

# http-proxy-host = kuzh.xxx.fr

# http-proxy-port = 8080
```

under these two files:

`/etc/subversion/servers`

`/home/<username>/.subversion/servers`

and that resolved the issue.
Apparently, local configs are generated for all users that are using svn, so you need to remove the proxy from your user account as well when you want to get rid of the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue trying a simple update on my server.

```
svn update
```

I received the same error `svn: OPTIONS of 'https://...': could not connect to server (https://...)`

I simply supplied my svn username and password once and it rectified the problem

```
svn update --username my_user_name --password xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Oracle Linux 6.6 64-bits as a VM guest (Windows 7 as host) behind company proxy, when I run command

```
svn co http://svn.code.sf.net/p/flashcard4cn/code/trunk flashcard4cn
```

got error message

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.code.sf.net/p/flashcard4cn/code/trunk': Could not resolve hostname `svn.code.sf.net': Host not found (http://svn.code.sf.net)
```

after added the following two lines under /home//.subversion/servers under [global]

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = proxy.**.com
http-proxy-port = 80
```

The errors went away, and check out successful. Some of you mentioned the same thing not worked, but it does work for me for Oracle Linux 6.6

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all answers posted before me, but none worked.

The only solution I found was simply restarting my laptop.

Then everything worked like before, no change needed in any svn config files etc.

I don't know why this happened, especially since no change was needed to fix this, meaning no change was done by me or any proxy changes were made neither.